What is the point of '!' in the git expression?
Why should I add '!' to this: git config --global alias.add-commit '!git add -A && git commit'
Does it work without '!', what is the point of '!' in this expression?
I didn't try that. I am just curious about that.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+alias+exclamation

BTW, @fkymon, welcome to posting on Stack Overflow! Check out [ask] for tips, like starting with your own research. To find the resources in my answer, I googled basically your question title: "What is the point of '!' in the git alias".


If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it will be treated as a shell command. For example, defining alias.new = !gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD [in the git config], the invocation git new is equivalent to running the shell command gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD.


git-config Documentation § alias.*


[...] maybe you want to run an external command, rather than a Git subcommand. In that case, you start the command with a ! character. This is useful if you write your own tools that work with a Git repository. We can demonstrate by aliasing git visual to run gitk:
$ git config --global alias.visual '!gitk'



Git Aliases - Git Basics


Based on git config docs:

If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it will
be treated as a shell command.

